# Spring MVC - CSS not being imported

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

So I tried hundreds of combinations, but nothing helps.

I have my JSP:

**about.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link href="resources/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen"/>

    <title>foo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/view/fragments/header.jsp" />
</header>

<div class="something">
<div class="container" id="alex" >
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="text-center" >
                <h1>Test</h1>

                <p class="lead">
                    bla bla bla
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<footer>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/view/fragments/footer.jsp" />
</footer>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the **bootstrap.min.css** which is being applied with no problem, and in the same directory I have:

**core.css**

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #6977f5;
}
```

Which for some reason has no effect on my **about.jsp** no matter its content.

I tried to change the reference, added the `base href`, removed **bootstrap.min.css**, but no matter what I do it simply doesn't work.

Comment: Thats weird.. try adding the contents of core.css in <style></style> inside the head tag instead of using a link and see if it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was actually wrong, it was just being cached by the browser, thus not showing the changes I was making.